# Confluent Kafka: How to start if localhost not set to default?

Tags: bash, apache-kafka, localhost, confluent-platform

Trying to get started with Confluent Kafka using this [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/quickstart.html):

The confluent platform is downloaded in the relevant directory: `/Users/dj/dev/kafka/confluent-3.3.0`

The doc says to run:

`$ confluent start`

Which returns:

`-bash: confluent: command not found`

Reading further the doc assumes the `services will run on localhost with default properties', and goes on to say 'If not already in your PATH, add Confluent’s bin directory by running':

`export PATH=<path-to-confluent>/bin:$PATH`

Which for me is:

`$ export PATH=</Users/dj/dev/kafka/confluent-3.3.0>/bin:$PATH`

Which returns:

`-bash: /bin:/Users/dj/anaconda/bin:/Users/dj/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin: No such file or directory`

It appears that my Anaconda installation is interfering with the bin path. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't include the angle-brackets. Try this instead:

```
export PATH=/Users/dj/dev/kafka/confluent-3.3.0/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the enterprise tar ball and not community tar ball.That worked for me